# Removing UIView From Subview clears the memory?

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am trying to add a UIView (ViewB) that contains a Graph and it uses a lot of memory into a superview (ViewA). The UIView is "Window System" so when the user clicks a button in ViewA the data is recalculated and the layout is redisplayed in ViewB.

My first approach was to add ViewB into ViewA and by inserting a Tag I could remove it From ViewA and re add it. I thought at the beginning that when a View is removed from the superview and the value assigned to nil the memory would be released. Turns out that ViewB is re added and The app ends up crashing due to a memory issue.

Here is my code. Is there anything I am doing wrong?

```
    func updateSoundWaveView(){

    if readFile.audioBuffer?.frameCapacity != 0{

        //NEW Setup
        if soundWaveContainer.viewWithTag(soundViewTag) != nil{
            waveView?.removeFromSuperview()
            waveView = nil
        }

        let totalWidth = windowTotalMinutes * 60 * 10
        print("\(logClassName): total Sound View Width = \(totalWidth)")

        waveView = SoundWaveView.init(withReadFile: readFile,
                                      containerFrame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                                             y: 0,
                                                             width: soundWaveContainer.frame.width,
                                                             height:  soundWaveContainer.frame.size.height),
                                      soundFrame: CGRect.init(x: 0,
                                                              y: 0,
                                                              width: CGFloat(totalWidth),
                                                              height: soundWaveContainer.frame.size.height)
        )

        /* Set UP Time Representation */
        waveView?.fractionsSeconds = 10
        waveView?.startMarkerPosition = startPosition - windowStart
        waveView?.endMarkerPosition = endPosition - windowStart
        waveView?.durationRepesentation = Int32(windowTotalMinutes) * 60 * 1000

        waveView?.tag = soundViewTag
        soundWaveContainer.addSubview(waveView!)

        /* Set Up Callbacks */
        waveView?.onTimeSelected = {newPosition in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.waveViewTimeSelected(newPosition: newPosition)
            }
        }
        waveView?.onMarkerSelected = {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.waveViewMarkerSelected()
            }
        }

        /* Not YET */
        //waveView?.drawSoundWave(fromSample: fromSample, toSample: toSample)

    }

}
```

EDIT.

Worth mention it that waveView is my ViewB, it is a custom Class and gets added into soundViewContainer ViewA which is and IBOutlet.

```
class SoundWaveView: UIView, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

//MARK: - Variables
//MARK: Constants

//MARK: Vars
var onTimeSelected:((CGFloat)->())?

var readFile:ReadFile

/*** UI ***/
var scrollView:UIScrollView = UIScrollView()
var waveView:UIView
var markerLeft:MarkerView?
var markerRight:MarkerView?

lazy private var middleY:CGFloat = { return frame.size.height/2 }()
var currentMarkerSelected = -1
var onMarkerSelected:(()->())?
//override class var layerClass: AnyClass { return CATiledLayer.self }


/*** Sound Representation ***/
/** View Time Representation **/
var fractionsSeconds:Int32 = 10

// in MiliSeconds
var startMarkerPosition:Int32 = 0
var startMarkerPositionInView:CGFloat = 0
var endMarkerPosition:Int32 = 0
var endMarkerPositionInView:CGFloat = 0

private var totalMinutes:CGFloat{
    get{
        return CGFloat(durationRepesentation)/60000
    }
}
private var totalSecond:CGFloat{
    return CGFloat(durationRepesentation)/1000
}
var durationRepesentation:Int32 = 0



/** WaveView representation **/
var samplesSeconds:Int = 10
var lineWidth:CGFloat = 0.20
var sampleSpace:CGFloat = 0.10



//MARK: - Lifecycle Methods
init(withReadFile readFile: ReadFile, containerFrame:CGRect, soundFrame: CGRect) {

    self.readFile = readFile

    waveView = UIView.init(frame: soundFrame)
    waveView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray

    scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: containerFrame)
    scrollView.addSubview(waveView)
    scrollView.contentSize = waveView.bounds.size

    super.init(frame: containerFrame)


}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func didMoveToSuperview() {
    setupView()
}



//MARK: - Helpers
private func setupView(){
    print("\(logClassName): setupView")

    addSubview(scrollView)

    startMarkerPositionInView = transformToGraphCordinates(position: startMarkerPosition)
    markerLeft = MarkerView(withView: self, color: .white, width: 2, title:"Start", position:startMarkerPositionInView, direction:.right)
    waveView.addSubview(markerLeft!)
    markerLeft?.triangleView?.tag = 0
    markerLeft?.triangleView?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(markerViewTouched)))


    endMarkerPositionInView = transformToGraphCordinates(position: endMarkerPosition)
    markerRight = MarkerView(withView: self, color: .white, width: 2, title:"End", position:endMarkerPositionInView, direction:.left)
    waveView.addSubview(markerRight!)
    markerRight?.triangleView?.tag = 1
    markerRight?.triangleView?.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(markerViewTouched)))

    print("\(logClassName): TEST -> endPoint = \(endMarkerPositionInView) VS View Width = \(waveView.frame.width)")

    /** Add Pan Gesture **/
    self.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    waveView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(viewTouched)))


}

private func transformToGraphCordinates(position:Int32)->CGFloat{

    let percentatgeEnd = ((totalMinutes * CGFloat(position)) / CGFloat(durationRepesentation))
    let endPositionInGraph:CGFloat = (percentatgeEnd * (totalMinutes * 60 * CGFloat(fractionsSeconds))) / (totalMinutes)

    return endPositionInGraph
}

@objc func markerViewTouched(tapGestureRecogniser:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    let tagView = tapGestureRecogniser.view!.tag
    print("\(logClassName): markerViewTouched \(tagView)")

    selectMarker(at: tagView)

}

@objc func viewTouched(tapGestureRecognizer:UITapGestureRecognizer){

    if currentMarkerSelected != -1{

        let tappedPosition = tapGestureRecognizer.location(in: tapGestureRecognizer.view)
        print("\(logClassName): viewTouched \(tappedPosition)")

        if currentMarkerSelected == 0{
            startMarkerPosition = Int32((tappedPosition.x / CGFloat(fractionsSeconds)) * 1000)
            startMarkerPositionInView = tappedPosition.x

            if startMarkerPositionInView < endMarkerPositionInView{
                markerLeft?.translateView(toPosition: startMarkerPositionInView)
                onTimeSelected?(tappedPosition.x)
            }

        }
        else if currentMarkerSelected == 1{
            endMarkerPosition = Int32((tappedPosition.x / CGFloat(fractionsSeconds)) * 1000)
            endMarkerPositionInView = tappedPosition.x

            if endMarkerPositionInView > startMarkerPositionInView{
                markerRight?.translateView(toPosition: endMarkerPositionInView)
                onTimeSelected?(tappedPosition.x)
            }

        }

    }

}
//MARK: - Methods
func drawSoundWave(fromSample:Int64, toSample:Int64){
    // Drawing code
    print("\(logClassName): Drawing from = \(fromSample) to \(toSample)")

    let soundPath = UIBezierPath()
    soundPath.lineWidth = lineWidth
    soundPath.move(to: CGPoint(x:0.0 , y: middleY))

    let testTo = Int64(toSample)


    let sequence = stride(from: fromSample, to: testTo, by: 4800)


    var testIndex = 0
    for element in sequence {

        let newSample:CGFloat? = CGFloat(readFile.audioBuffer?.floatChannelData?.pointee.advanced(by: Int(element)).pointee ?? 0)

        /** Continuous View **/
        let nextPoint = CGPoint(x: soundPath.currentPoint.x + sampleSpace,
                                y: middleY - ((newSample ?? 0) * 100) - 1.0)

        soundPath.addLine(to: nextPoint)
        soundPath.move(to: nextPoint)

        testIndex += 1

    }

    let trackLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    trackLayer.path = soundPath.cgPath

    self.layer.addSublayer(trackLayer)

    trackLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineWidth = 0.10
    trackLayer.fillColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    trackLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound

}

func moveMarker(withId id:Int, toPosition position:Int32){

    switch id {
    case 0:
        startMarkerPosition = position
        startMarkerPositionInView = transformToGraphCordinates(position: position)
        markerLeft?.translateView(toPosition: startMarkerPositionInView)
    case 1:
        endMarkerPosition = position
        endMarkerPositionInView = transformToGraphCordinates(position: position)
        markerRight?.translateView(toPosition: endMarkerPositionInView)
    default:
        break
    }

}

func selectMarker(at tagView:Int){

    /** Left Marker **/
    if tagView == 0{

        if currentMarkerSelected == -1{
            currentMarkerSelected = 0
            markerLeft!.isSelected = true
        }
        else if currentMarkerSelected == 1{
            currentMarkerSelected = 0
            markerLeft?.isSelected = true
            markerRight?.isSelected = false
        }
        else if currentMarkerSelected == 0{
            currentMarkerSelected = -1
            markerLeft?.isSelected = false
        }

    }
    else if tagView == 1{

        if currentMarkerSelected == -1{
            currentMarkerSelected = 1
            markerRight!.isSelected = true
        }
        else if currentMarkerSelected == 0{
            currentMarkerSelected = 1
            markerRight?.isSelected = true
            markerLeft?.isSelected = false
        }
        else if currentMarkerSelected == 1{
            currentMarkerSelected = -1
            markerRight?.isSelected = false
        }

    }

    onMarkerSelected?()

}
```

}

After 8 calls to the function the memory used is 1 GB . and then app crashes...
[image]

Comment: Is this waveView declared as a weak var? Weak vars get automatically released once no object has reference to them.

Comment: It is not declared as weak variable. I am going to see if that was the issue

Comment: now the app crashes due Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when waveView is added. I have declared as weak on the top of my class

Comment: Well waveView is optional and can be nil. You are force unwrapping it which can cause a crash if it’s nil.  Can the initializer produce nil? Does it crash when you add it to soundWaveContainer?

Comment: In your case when you declare variable as weak, it gets deallocated immediately after allocation. So, no wonder that it crashes on force unwrap.

Comment: I have updated the question With the Initialisation of the WaveView Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
waveView?.onTimeSelected = {newPosition in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.waveViewTimeSelected(newPosition: newPosition)
    }
}
waveView?.onMarkerSelected = {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.waveViewMarkerSelected()
    }
}
```

shouldn't a weak self be used? something like

```
waveView?.onTimeSelected = {[weak self] _, newPosition in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self?.waveViewTimeSelected(newPosition: newPosition)
    }
}
waveView?.onMarkerSelected = {
    DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] _ in
        self.waveViewMarkerSelected()
    }
}
```

if I am not wrong not using a weak self create a retain cycle, your view won't be deallocated while "self" still exists.

Comment: That indeed was the issue! Thank you. Now the view gets dealloacated. you never think about this things until you managed huge amount of data. Every time it was allocated in memory it was taking 150MB!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use view tagging here. You may just check for `superview` of your `waveView` to know whether it needs to be removed. Something like this:

   ```
   if waveView?.superview != nil {
           waveView?.removeFromSuperview()
           waveView = nil
   }
   ```
2. Do not use `weak` var then.
3. `MarkerView` is initialized with `SoundWaveView`, if it retains in some way then you will have a retain cycle, because `SoundWaveView` instance has 2 instances of `MarkerView` as its' subviews.

Also you may check Xcode memory graph which is a great way to find memory leaks.

Comment: It still happens... Is it something to do with the way WaveView is implemented?

Comment: Please, post the output of your error. Yes, the problem may be in your WaveView implementation, if you have, for example, retain cycles there.

Comment: @ReimondHill please see my updated answer, 3d point. Can you post MarkerView implementation?

Comment: is it possible that the closures retain?

Comment: @ReimondHill sure.